# How is Image metadata passed?

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a method which uploads an image (IFormFile) to blob storage

```
if (StorageHelper.IsImage(photo))
{
    if (photo.Length > 0)
    {
        using (Stream stream = photo.OpenReadStream())
        {
             await StorageHelper.UploadFileToStorage(stream, photo.FileName, _storageConfig);
        }
    }
}
```

Once the file is in storage I am able to open and view certain metadata properties such as device, date taken, location, etc. However when debugging and inspection the photo object which is an `IFormFile` I can't find any of these details except for file name and file size etc.

I would like to find these extra properties and save them into a SQL table which already contains the photos URL and other information, how/where are these values passed and am I able to access them?

Comment: I would expect the information is embedded in the file itself with [exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) tags.

Comment: Very useful,thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Imaging_PropertyItem_Id

Answer (score -1):

Having read Justin's comment I found this:

[Exif extractor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36342/ExifLib-A-Fast-Exif-Data-Extractor-for-NET)

and was able to extract the data I needed.

Thanks again

Comment: [When someone goes on Stack Overflow, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: Who is Justin?.